# ESP32 attachInterrupt causing (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1)

Tags: arduino, scale, esp32

Been trying all day to figure out what could be causing the problem but to no avail. Every time I try to call an attachInterrupt, even if the ISR function is completely empty I get this:

```
05:32:40.700 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Interrupt wdt timeout on CPU1). 
05:32:40.765 -> 
05:32:40.765 -> Core  1 register dump:
05:32:40.797 -> PC      : 0x4008e2d2  PS      : 0x00060c35  A0      : 0x8008d246  A1      : 0x3ffb20a0  
05:32:40.893 -> A2      : 0x3ffb7618  A3      : 0x3ffb81a4  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x00060c23  
05:32:40.990 -> A6      : 0x00060c23  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x3ffb81a4  A9      : 0x00000018  
05:32:41.085 -> A10     : 0x3ffb81a4  A11     : 0x00000018  A12     : 0x3ffc2bdc  A13     : 0x00060c23  
05:32:41.181 -> A14     : 0x007bf3d8  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x00000019  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000006  
05:32:41.277 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x40088f10  LEND    : 0x40088f1b  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  
05:32:41.374 -> 
05:32:41.374 -> Backtrace: 0x4008e2cf:0x3ffb20a0 0x4008d243:0x3ffb20c0 0x4008c5d6:0x3ffb20e0 0x400e2216:0x3ffb2120 0x400e2315:0x3ffb2150 0x400d5d01:0x3ffb2170 0x400d5da9:0x3ffb21c0 0x400d3c3e:0x3ffb21f0 0x400d3c91:0x3ffb2220 0x400d21c9:0x3ffb2240 0x400d1a2e:0x3ffb2260 0x400d4e26:0x3ffb2290
05:32:41.662 -> 
05:32:41.662 -> 
05:32:41.662 -> Core  0 register dump:
05:32:41.709 -> PC      : 0�
```

Couldn't find any solution to anything similar unfortunately.

```cpp
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      display.begin();
      display.setFont(u8g2_font_profont29_tr);
      display.firstPage();
      do {
        display.setCursor(0, 16);
        display.println(F("not your"));
        display.setCursor(0, 16 + 23);
        display.println(F(" average"));
        display.setCursor(0, 16 + 46);
        display.println(F("  scale"));
      } while (display.nextPage());
      long splashStartMillis = millis();

      // Serial.println(F("Starting scale..."));
      hx711.begin(LOADCELL_DOUT_PIN, LOADCELL_SCK_PIN);
      watchDigitalPin(COFFEE_BUTTON_PIN);

      Serial.println("test");

      // Prime the scale and then zero while splash screen is up.
      long delayUntilMillis = splashStartMillis + 1000;
      while (millis() < delayUntilMillis) {
        ascale.readRaw();
      }
      ascale.zero( /*sampleCount=*/ 5);
    }

    void IRAM_ATTR handleButtonPress() {
      const unsigned long isr_millis = millis();
      int events = 0;
      int myBounces = 0;
      for (PinStatus * ps = pinStatuses; ps != nullptr; ps = ps - > nextPinStatus) {
        uint8_t state = digitalRead(ps - > pin);
        // Warning: overflow after 50 days.
        if (isr_millis >= ps - > nextStateMillis) {
          if (state != ps - > state) {
            // Lock in a button press for 200ms.
            ps - > newEvent = true;
            ps - > nextStateMillis = isr_millis + debounceDelayMs;
          }
          if (state != ps - > state || state != ps - > nextState) {
            events++;
          }
          ps - > state = ps - > nextState = state;

        } else {
          if (state != ps - > state) {
            myBounces++;
          }
          // Bounce!
          ps - > nextState = state;
        }
      }
      if (events == 0 && myBounces == 0) {
        phantoms++;
      }
      bounces += myBounces;
    }

    void watchDigitalPin(uint8_t pin) {
      noInterrupts();

      pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP);

      PinStatus * ps = new PinStatus();
      ps - > pin = pin;
      ps - > state = digitalRead(pin);
      ps - > nextState = ps - > state;
      ps - > nextPinStatus = pinStatuses;
      pinStatuses = ps;

      // watched_digital_pins |= (1 << pin);

      
      #if defined(__AVR__)
        *digitalPinToPCMSK(pin) |= bit(digitalPinToPCMSKbit(pin)); // enable pin
      PCIFR |= bit(digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // clear any outstanding interrupt
      PCICR |= bit(digitalPinToPCICRbit(pin)); // enable interrupt for the group
      
      #else
        attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), handleButtonPress, CHANGE);
      #endif

      interrupts();
    }
```

I do not do any arduino programming if it was not obvious.

I tried to even call an empty ISR but same issue, all problems go away when I remove the  attachInterrupt.

Comment: put # in the same line for Preprocessor Macro, you will then not missing the # in `#endif`.

Comment: My apologies, I edited the code in the post, I think it got messy when I copied it.

Comment: If that for loop is blocking in the ISR while you debounce the button then that's a huge problem.  Button presses are slow, you don't need interrupts to handle them.  That just adds complexity.  But if you do use an interrupt, it has to be very very short.  An interrupt is not a place to stop and wait for something.

Comment: On a side note, the debounce code you have is broken at rollover.  If you rewrite it with subtraction then it will work even at rollover.  See the "Blink WIthout Delay" example in the Arduino IDE for an example of how to rearrange the math.